# Separate QByteArray hex values to separate int's

Tags: c++, qt, parsing

How can I parse these `"\"` separated HEX values in the `QByteArray` into 8 separate int's?

```
QByteArray mainArray = "\xFF\xFF\x01\x04\x01\x0B\x03\xEC";
int num1;
int num2;
int num3;
...
```

Comment: The [`QByteArray`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html) has an `operator[]` as well as a `size()` method. It can be used similar like a `std::vector`.

Comment: Are you aware that the actual parsing of `"\xFF"` is already done in the C++ compiler? It is how string constants are compiled but has nothing to do with `QByteArray`. If you access `mainArray[0]` you will get `255` (or as hex `0xFF`).

Comment: I did try mainArray[0] (and 1 and 2..) however these contain random symbols like ÿ and a box with an x in it (it won't show up in the comments).

Comment: The reason is that `255` printed as `char` (in your locale) is `ÿ`. Do instead: `int num0 = mainArray[0];` and then try e.g. `qDebug() << num0;` and you will realize that I'm right.

Comment: Using this method mainArray[0] returns -1.  However it did work correctly with mainArray[2] and [3].  Any idea why?

Comment: Ah. There is still one pitfall: The [`QByteArray::operator[]`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#operator-5b-5d-2) returns `char`. `(char)0xFF` converted to `int` could cause a [sign-extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension). To prevent this definitely, the following fix should help: `int num0 = (unsigned char)mainArray[0];` But now it **should** work.

Comment: There we go! Worked perfectly.  Thank you so much!

Comment: An alternative would have been: `int num0 = mainArray[0] & 0xFF`. Instead of intermediate conversion over `unsigned char` it just cuts away the bits set due to sign extension.

Comment: Would either method be faster or cleaner once the program is large enough for it to matter?

Comment: The intermediate conversion probably doesn't cause any extra code. It just gives the compiler hints how to handle the values. But, on the other hand, `&` is probably one of the cheapest operations. Don't care too much about this. If you really want see the effect then compile your code on [godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/) and compare the assembler code. But IMHO it isn't worth the effort...

Comment: Alright, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The `\x` [escape sequence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) represents a hexadecimal value within string literals and character literals. The two hexadecimal digits following the `\x` will be parsed as a single byte. For example:

```
QByteArray foo1 = "\x46\x6f\x6f";
QByteArray foo2 = "Foo";

Q_ASSERT(foo1 == foo2); // 'foo1' and 'foo2' are equal
```

If you wish to access the hexadecimally represented values in your `mainArray`, simply use the [`QByteArray::at`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#at) or the [subscript operator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#operator-5b-5d) as follows:

```
QByteArray mainArray = "\xFF\xFF\x01\x04\x01\x0B\x03\xEC";
int num1 = mainArray[0]; // 0xFF
int num2 = mainArray[1]; // 0xFF
int num3 = mainArray[2]; // 0x01
// ...
```

One thing to keep in mind, the value type of `QByteArray` is `char` which is a signed type, therefore the `\xFF` on most systems will be `-1` insead of `255`. To fix the mentioned issue, here is a possible solution:

```
QByteArray mainArray = "\xFF\xFF\x01\x04\x01\x0B\x03\xEC";
int num1 = 0xff & mainArray[0];
int num2 = 0xff & mainArray[1];
int num3 = 0xff & mainArray[2];
// ...
```

Comment: `int num1 = mainArray[0];` causes an issue (as pointed out in one of my comments). It doesn't provide `0xFF` but `0xFFFFFFFF` (assuming 32 bit `int` and `char` which are signed by default) due to sign extension (though it might work on compilers where `char` is unsigned by default). I also mentioned in another comment how to fix it.

Comment: @Scheff, thank you for your remark, I expanded my answer.